# How to Call the Custom UIView from ViewController using Frame Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, call

I want to show the `CustomUIView` From my `ViewController`.How to call using frame?I am getting Confused in Frame as am a newbie.
My Theme is,I Want to show the `LoginViewKarnataka` and `usernameLabel` in my `ViewController` in the y Value 150.
This is My Code

ViewController.m

```
LoginViewKarnataka *loginView = [[LoginViewKarnataka alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

LoginViewKarnataka(CustomUIView)

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
NSLog(@"frame==>>%f",frame);
if (self)
{
    UILabel *usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 20)];
    [usernameLabel setText:@"username"];
    [usernameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your viewController code to

```
LoginViewKarnataka *loginView = [[LoginViewKarnataka alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

In your LoginViewKarnataka view

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self)
 {
   [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   UILabel *usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 20)];
   [usernameLabel setText:@"username"];
   [usernameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   [self addSubview:label];
  }
 return self;
}
```

In your above code, you are adding a label at the positions of x: 20, y: 20.
To print frame of any view use following code.

```
    NSLog(@"frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
```

To print size of any view

```
    NSLog(@"frame : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
```

Comment: If i want to print frame size of a view by doing like this means it shows error Property 'View' not found on object 'LoginViewKarnataka'.

Comment: Its not showing `LoginViewkarnataka` and also `usernameLabel`.Please Check and update a correct solution bro.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. For confirmation I have added background color as red color to karnatakView . Post screenshot if any issues.

Comment: Thanks its Working.But old View Values disaapears.I need Old values.

Comment: You have to change the frame position of LoginViewKarnataka. This view might be overlapping your controller elements. change 'x' and 'y' position of LoginViewKarnataka and try. That will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101262/discussion-between-raghunath-and-bharath-vankireddy).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. All that was missing was adding usernameLabel as a subview to your custom view.

```
[self addSubview:usernameLabel];
```

P.S. If you need to log any frame values then you can simply log the view. The frame value is printed in the description of the view. Also you can use [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect) for UI debugging if you have created any complex UI.

Thanks.